# How do I automatically delete an orphaned entity in my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, entity, orphan

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  Is there a way to automatically delete an orphaned entity when I no longer have an object pointing to it?  I have these two models …

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address, :autosave => true, dependent: :destroy


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :my_object
```

and in my PostGres “my_objects” table I have an “address_id” column that is a foreign key to the addresses table.  Below is my method I use to save my “MyObject” entity with its accompanying address object …

```
  def save_with_address(params)
    transaction do
      if !params[:address].nil?
        # Address isn't an object yet, it is just a bunch of parameters
        params[:address][:state] = params[:address][:state].nil? ? nil : State.find_by_id(params[:address][:state])
        params[:address][:country] = params[:address][:country].nil? ? nil : Country.find_by_id(params[:address][:country])
        address = Address.new(params[:address])
        address.user = self
        address.save
        self.address = address
      end

      # Save the object
      save
    end
  end
```

But I’m noticing that if the my_object entity had an address object before, that object remains in the database, despite the fact that it is orphaned.  What is the easiest way to adjust things so that my orphaned address entity is removed from the database?

Answer (score 1):

just update your model as below

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address, :autosave => true


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :my_object, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: I changed my models per your direction but this didn't work.  The orphan address record remains.

Comment: can you please explain what exactly you need to do.